# how to exclude particular class from beautiful soup (python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

```
import requests

source = requests.get('http://photographyblogger.net/26-beautiful-horse-pictures/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")


post = soup.find('article','full')
title = post.h2.text

for summery in post.find_all('p'):      
    rest = post.find("p", "wp-caption-text");
    rest.decompose()
    print(summery.text)
```

what i wanted to achieve is print title , print content and then print caption but currently without using rest i am getting all content and caption together.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsvM6.png) as you can see if i use this code i am getting what i intend but there is some error

Answer (score 0):

It seems your loop over `post.find_all('p')` lists all `'p'` elements, while inside the loop you are calling `find()` on the entire `'post'` element, if there is fewer `"p", "wp-caption-text"` elements then `'summery'`, then your `rest` lines will be empty, which means that calling `.decompose()` on an empty string gives error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'`, while you can still see all the line that you expect.